# Populate array in for loop (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have js code

```
var model = {
    start: newstart,
    end: newstop,
    imei: imei
};
$.ajax({
    url: dburl,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    data: model,
    success: function (data) {
         speeddata = data;

         if (speeddata.length !== 0) {
             for (var i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
                 path = "path=" + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + ',' + speeddata[i].Longitude2;
                 var googleurl = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?"
                     + path + "&key=" + roadsapikey;
                 + path + "&key=" + roadsapikey;
                 $.ajax({
                     url: googleurl,
                     dataType: 'json',
                     type: 'GET',
                     success: function (data) {

                         for (var i = 0; i < data.speedLimits.length; i++) {
                             speedobject.push({
                                 speedlimits: data.speedLimits[i].speedLimit
                             });
                         }
                         console.log(speedobject);
                     }

                 });
             }

         }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

In this code I get data from db and write it to `speeddata` array, I have 6 elements in array.

```
   var speeddata = [{
Imei: 35745407257535, Latitude2: 50.9364, Longitude2: 3.12147, Speed: 8
},{
Imei: 35745407257535, Latitude2: 50.93918, Longitude2: 3.12485, Speed: 37
},{
Imei: 35745407257535, Latitude2: 50.93997, Longitude2: 3.12837, Speed: 7
},{
Imei: 35745407257535, Latitude2: 50.93834, Longitude2: 3.12893, Speed: 54
},{
Imei: 35745407257535, Latitude2: 50.9281, Longitude2: 3.13903, Speed: 56
},{
Imei: 35745407257535, Latitude2: 50.9219, Longitude2: 3.15888, Speed: 9
}];
```

After this I need to get speedlimit for every element in `speeddata` and write it to speedobject.

I try to it like here

```
 if (speeddata.length !== 0) {
             for (var i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
                 path = "path=" + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + ',' + speeddata[i].Longitude2;
                 var googleurl = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?"
                     + path + "&key=" + roadsapikey;
                 + path + "&key=" + roadsapikey;
                 $.ajax({
                     url: googleurl,
                     dataType: 'json',
                     type: 'GET',
                     success: function (data) {

                         for (var i = 0; i < data.speedLimits.length; i++) {
                             speedobject.push({
                                 speedlimits: data.speedLimits[i].speedLimit
                             });
                         }
                         console.log(speedobject);
                     }

                 });
             }

         }
```

But I have 6 repeats when `console.log` speedobject.

Here is array

[Screen of google api array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN4ed.png)

So if I want to display it in table I will have 36 entries instead of 6

Where is my trouble?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Can you give a fiddle link and data object w/o the AJAX call?

Comment: One  second, I will post it@Pavan

Comment: I cannot create fiddle, because it will have google roads api key. But I included speeddata data@Pavan

Comment: And what do you want?

Comment: After this I need to get speedlimit for every element in speeddata and write it to speedobject. I writed in post all info about me trouble @Pavan

Comment: You need to handle async behaviour of javascript. You can't have the second AJAX call in the for loop. I prefer to use async.js library. In your case you can use async.map function. See how it works.

Comment: You talk about this? https://caolan.github.io/async/ @Pavan

Comment: But how I can do this without external scripts?@Pavan

Comment: You are making it unnecessarily complicated , 
how many speedLimits one data will have?
And how you want to hold that data and have a connection with speeddata

Comment: only one speedlimit@Viplock

Comment: In that case why you added speedobject and added limit to it ? let me add one answer for you

Comment: Speeddata will be array and I need to get speedlimits that will be also array. So after this I can merge it. I have code for merge. But now I have trouble in loop@Viplock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code like

```
 if (speeddata.length !== 0) {
             for (var i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
                 path = "path=" + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + ',' + speeddata[i].Longitude2;
                 var googleurl = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?"
                     + path + "&key=" + roadsapikey;
                 + path + "&key=" + roadsapikey;
                 $.ajax({
                     url: googleurl,
                     dataType: 'json',
                     async: false, 
                     type: 'GET',
                     success: function (data) {

                             speeddata[i].speedlimits=data.speedLimits;

                     }

                 });
             }

         }
```

Updated the success function.

add comment if some problem

Edit: I have added `async: false,` to the call by that you will be able to fill speeddata object in it. 
Oter way is to make a callback by refactoring the code

Comment: `Cannot set property 'speedlimits' of undefined`

Comment: I will now post screen of response from google and update post

Comment: how this data object is like `success: function (data) {`...

what is in data you are geeting from ajex call?

Comment: I paste screen shot in post.

Comment: can you access `speeddata` inside success?

Comment: Yes. when I set `console.log(speeddata)` I see data of `speeddata`

Comment: thats `speedobject` !!

Comment: Don't understood. you write about speeddata

Answer (score 1):

As I understood it, you want to have 6 entries each with an array of speedlimits, like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    var speedLimits = []
    for (var i = 0; i< data.speedLimits.length;i++) {
        speedLimits.push(data.speedLimits[i].speedLimit);
    }
    speedobject.push({speedLimits: speedLimits})
    console.log(speedobject);
}
```

Comment: Nope. I need need to get speedLimit property for every element in speeddata. I updated post, check it.